# PHP simplexml Entities

Tags: simplexml, php, entities

What's going one here?

```
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <album>
        <img src="002.jpg" caption="w&aacute;ssup?" />
    </album>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
// $xmlobj = simplexml_load_file("xml.xml"); // same thing

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($xml);
echo "</pre>";
```

Error:

> Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 5: parser error : Entity 'aacute' not defined

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`&aacute` is not an [XML entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) - you're thinking about HTML.

Special characters are usually used "as is" in XML - an `html_entity_decode()` on the input data (don't forget to specify UTF-8 as the character set) should do the trick:

```
$string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
```

Comment: Pekka, in my example if I do: $xmlStr = file_get_contents("xml.xml");
$xml = html_entity_decode($xmlStr, ENT_QUOTES); I get caption="w�ssup?"

Comment: @FFish did you add the `utf-8`?

Comment: No, i didn't! To much input in a few minutes. It work's now :-)

Comment: I was having problem reading from an XML file with encoding="iso-8859-1" and inserting in a db with utf-8 (the field in the row was truncated at the first accented char while the print_r was perfect). Adding "utf-8" to html_entity_decode resolved. Thanks.

Comment: But caption add `&lt;`, still can't parse. See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fb962cefbb4495afc247c783b6a4b3c722ab75e0

Answer (score 2):

i had this problem the other day.
any occurrence of & will need to be inside a CDATA tag

```
<album>
    <img src="002.jpg" />
    <caption><![CDATA[now you can put whatever characters you need & include html]]></caption>
</album>
```

to keep the parser from failing.

Comment: Good point if the `img` tag is supposed to remain HTML. Depending on what the OP wants, it's either this or decoding the entities.

Comment: Yeah but I can't use CDATA, the XML files need to be like this. With the caption in the attribute. Pekka, how can I decode the entities? Should I get the XML string with file_get_contents() and than decode than?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at [Matt Robinson's article](http://inanimatt.com/php-convert-entities.php) on an alternative method: **Converting named entities to numeric in PHP** . It mentions the `html_entity_decode` method (already pointed out by another answer) and some potential pitfalls:

> There are two possible problems with this approach. The first is invalid entities: `html_entity_decode()` won't touch them, which means you'll still get XML errors. The second is encoding. I suppose it's possible that you don't actually want `UTF-8`. You should, because it's awesome, but maybe you have a good reason. If you don't tell `html_entity_decode()`  to use `UTF-8`, it won't convert entities that don't exist in the character set you specify. If you tell it to output in UTF-8 and then use something like `iconv()` to convert it, then you'll lose any characters that aren't in the output encoding.

Also, if you find the script rather cumbersome, you can also use the one [shared on SourceRally](http://www.sourcerally.net/Scripts/39-Convert-HTML-Entities-to-XML-Entities).

Comment: Ok, but how do I get the data in? With file_get_contents()?

Comment: $feed = file_get_contents( 'xml.xml' );
    // do whatever you need to the string so the parser wont barf here...
    $xmlObj = simplexml_load_string( $feed );

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to change

`"w&aacute;ssup?" 
to 
"w&amp;aacute;ssup?"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this func `simplexml_load_entity_string`

```
<?php

$string = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <album>
        <img src="002.jpg" caption="test&lt;w&aacute;ssup?" />
    </album>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_entity_string($string);

var_dump($xml);

function simplexml_load_entity_string($string = '')
{
    // cover entity except Predefined entities in XML
    $string = str_replace([
        '&quot;', '&amp;', '&apos;', '&lt;', '&gt;',
    ], [
        'SPECIALquotMARK', 'SPECIALampMARK', 'SPECIALaposMARK', 'SPECIALltMARK', 'SPECIALgtMARK',
    ], $string);
    $string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
    $string = str_replace([
        'SPECIALquotMARK', 'SPECIALampMARK', 'SPECIALaposMARK', 'SPECIALltMARK', 'SPECIALgtMARK',
    ], [
        '&quot;', '&amp;', '&apos;', '&lt;', '&gt;',
    ], $string);

    // load xml
    return simplexml_load_string($string);
}
```