# Failed loading XML:xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

When I try to Import xml file, it returns an error:

> xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value `4"` because of `$amp;` in xml `<STOCKGROUP >NAME="ABC &amp; Glass" RESERVEDNAME="">`

Here is code I'm using to read xml file data

```
function add_product_type()
{
    print_r($_FILES);
    if (isset($_FILES['product_type_file']) && ($_FILES['product_type_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)) {
        $use_errors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $response = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['product_type_file']['tmp_name']);
        print_r($response);
        foreach($response->BODY->IMPORTDATA as $key => $value) {
            foreach($value->REQUESTDATA->TALLYMESSAGE as $key => $values) {
                if (strstr("&amp;", $values->STOCKGROUP->attributes())) {
                    $name = str_replace("&amp;", "&", $values->STOCKGROUP->attributes());
                }
                else {
                    $name = $values->STOCKGROUP->attributes();
                }

                echo $name . ",";
            }
        }

        if ($response == false) {
            echo "Failed loading XML\n";
            foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
                echo "\t", $error->message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: IT sounds like the XML you're trying to read has a syntax error. Can you post an example document?

Comment: xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 4 this error occurs

Comment: No, post a complete example of the XML data you're trying to parse. The XML in the error message looks very broken, but since it's a fragment it's not possible to tell.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16aI_-TE3TGb6N4K58mA2w9I3DLiuyeFQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML has no notion of HTML entities. As a hack, you can [decode the entities first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2850749/2652567) with

```
$html = html_entity_decode($file_contents, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");
```

and then try parse `$html` with the XML parser. Just hope it's tolerant enough, because HTML is still not valid XML.

The good news is that you can then remove the `if (strstr("&amp;",` hack because that is taken care of by `html_entity_decode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML sample isn't the same data as your getting the error with and processes OK, but this doesn't mean that your code is correct.  In
your main loop, you use `$values->STOCKGROUP->attributes()` as the name, but if you did a `print_r()` of this value, you will see it comes out with a list of all of the attribute values and your code will combine them all into one string.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => Alluminium Section & Glass
            [RESERVEDNAME] => 
        )

)
```

If you just want the NAME attribute of `<STOCKGROUP NAME="Alluminium Section &amp; Glass" RESERVEDNAME="">`, then use `STOCKGROUP['NAME']`.  Also rather than just substitute `&amp;`, use  `html_entity_decode()` to convert any characters in the name.

```
foreach($response->BODY->IMPORTDATA as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value->REQUESTDATA->TALLYMESSAGE as $key => $values) {
        $name = html_entity_decode((string)$values->STOCKGROUP['NAME']);    
        echo $name . ",";
    }
}
```

This code with the sample you provide outputs...

```
Alluminium Section & Glass,
```

**Update:**
Check the file being loaded...

```
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['product_type_file']['tmp_name']);
echo $data;
$use_errors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$response = simplexml_load_string($data);
echo $response->asXML();
```

Comment: print_r($response) How to print

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => Alluminium Section & Glass
            [RESERVEDNAME] => 
        )

)

Comment: If you want to print a SimpleXMLElement - use `echo $response->asXML();`

Comment: when  i use echo $response->asXML();  
 => give me this error ->Call to a member function asXML() on boolean in

Comment: This means the XML isn't correct - BUT the sample data you gave works, so this either isn't the same data or isn't the complete data.

Comment: This is my xml file link you can use => https://drive.google.com/file/d/16aI_-TE3TGb6N4K58mA2w9I3DLiuyeFQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I've added a new part of the code to the answer - the XML you sent still works, so make sure this is the XML that is being loaded.  So load the file, output it to see what it's getting and then try and load it.

Comment: file are completely decoded but end echo $response->asXML(); so,
Call to a member function asXML() on boolean

Comment: Does the output look exactly the same as the XML file you sent above?

Comment: No output look like 
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => Alluminium Section & Glass
            [RESERVEDNAME] => 
        )

)

Comment: (Sorry for the delay) Where is this output coming from?  It looks like the output of the `STOCKGROUP` attributes.  What is the output of `echo $data;` (comment out all other `echo` and `print_r`)

Comment: When I"m echo $data that time output come in decoded from like 

��<ENVELOPE>

  <HEADER>

    <TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>

  </HEADER>

  <BODY>

    <IMPORTDATA>

      <REQUESTDESC>

        <REPORTNAME>All Masters</REPORTNAME>

        <STATICVARIABLES>

Comment: The �� should definitely not be there, but also check if the `Section & Glass` is `Section &amp; Glass`

Comment: (First fall sorry Nigel yesterday i"m there)  When I'm run simple .xml file on browser that also give smae error => **" error on line 1317 at column 24: xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 4 "** so it's problem on .xml file. 
another thing is .xml file i"m not created it's genrated by **Tally system**  so...

Comment: This looks like there is something like &#04; difficulty is that the file you've attached as sample data doesn't contain this, so I can't  tell what it's doing.